# How to handle nested property in object when object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, multidimensional-array

Usually my object is full but sometimes it doesnt return all the needed properties or it returns but as null. How do I handle the nested property when the object is undefined?

My JS code is: `typeof property.inside !== 'undefined' ? property.inside : null;`

but this just returns 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: property is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1` 
instead of `null`

Comment: That means that the outer `property` is null, not that the inner `inside` check failed.

Comment: You are asking about a 'nested' property, but your error is complaining about `property`, which from your snippet is not a nested variable.

Comment: Please share an dummy object where your condition ins failing

Comment: I understand but either property could be null at any time the inner or outer one. I need to handle in both cases

Comment: Then you could try `(property || {}).inside`

Comment: same `Uncaught ReferenceError: property is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1` error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hk04q82e/  I don't get that error.

Comment: typeof (property && property.inside !== 'undefined' )? property.inside : null; use this instead, you need to check if property is null or not.

Comment: @Taplar your example will still throw an error because you did not update true result evaluation which is property.inside. i think he assume he will only update the condition part of the expression.

Comment: What update?  The question is just asking about accessing.

Comment: @ngeksyo add that as an answer I'll change my code to check for this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hk04q82e/3/  I'm not understanding what you think the issue is with this @ngeksyo

Comment: my bad, i did not look at it closely. @Taplar

Comment: @ngeksyo your jsfiddle solution works perfectly. Please add this as an answer and I will accept